# Regex excluding characters from positions in words

Tags: c++, regex

I've been trying to match a pattern excluding a certain char.

Lets say the characters given is "h...o", and I want to match all words not including a certain char, let's say 'c'
I've tried a ton of different ways of going about this.
Some of those include,

```
"h^[c]^[c]^[c]o"

"h(!?c)(?!c)(!?c)o"
```

But none of those works, does anyone know whats up?

the point of this is kind of like a cheating hang man, where I return all the words not containing the guess.

```
vector<string> getWords(string currentWord, char guess){
    for(auto& i: currentWord){
        string reg = ""
        if(i == '_'){
           string t = [[regex expression for acception any char except 'guess']]
           reg += t;
        }else{
          reg += i;  
        }
    }

  return getMatchingWords(mapOfWords, reg)
}
```

Only accepting all words that doesn't contain the guess doesn't work here as the exclusion is indexbound

Comment: Brute force does not really help here :) What do you consider a word? How can you define the boundaries for these "words"? I am asking because `.` is not a word char (from the regex point of view)

Comment: it's from a dictionary

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet illustrating the problem? An [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: edited the uestion

Comment: Sorry, does not it mean you iterate over the string and check some specific substrings for the presence of the `guess` char? You might check [Check if a string contains a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340281/) rather than look for a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression `h^[c]^[c]^[c]o` doesn't work, because it looks for `h`, followed by a `^`, followed by a `c`, and so on.

To negate a character set, you must put the caret `^` inside the brackets, see [Negated Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). In your case, this would be

```
h[^c][^c][^c]o
```

Now it looks for `h`, followed by any character *not* `c`, followed by another character *not* `c`, ...