# How to check for a character sequence in a .text file using C++?

Tags: c++, file

I have a .txt file which contains a continuous sequence of characters (without spaces). I wanted to search for a sequence of characters in the .txt file and am having trouble doing that.

```
ifstream fin;
    fin.open("sample.txt");
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == 'p' && ch + 1 == 'o' && ch + 2 == 'w')
            std::cout << "Sequence found" << "\n";
    }
    fin.close();
```

Comment: Consider the following program: `int main() { char c = 'p'; std::cout << c << c + 1 << c + 2; }`.  Will it print `pow`?

Comment: Unrelated, but still a major problem with your code: [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: You need to create a byte buffer (for instance an byte array) and then invoke the `.read(buffer, bufferSize)` function on the `fin` to read from the file to the buffer. Check the example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/

Answer (score 2):

That won't work, `ch` is the character you read in, but `ch + 1` isn't the next character (that you haven't read in yet). It's just `ch` increased by `1`, so that's the next letter in the alphabet, the digit one bigger, etc. depending on what `ch` is anyway.

If you just want to see whether a sequence is in a file, then I would read in the file into an `std::string` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/116220/10411602) says:

```
std::string slurp(std::ifstream& in) {
    std::stringstream sstr;
    sstr << in.rdbuf();
    return sstr.str();
}
```

So you pass that function your `fin` and you get a string containing your file's content. Then you try to find your sequence like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340309/10411602) explains:

```
if (myString.find("pow") != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "found!" << '\n';
}
```