# Check if each string in file have only one word

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file, iostream

> Input:
>   [1-st string]Dog
>
> [2-nd string]I love dog
>
> [3-rd string]Dog love me
>
> [4-th string]Love
>
> Output:
>   [1-st string]Dog
>
> [2-nd string]Love
>
> How can i do such thing in c++ ?>Without using vector.Thx:)

Comment: What is the description of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a question in the format "No A is within a class B". The algorithm for such problem is

```
bool wrong = false;
while ( /* there is another A */ )
{
   if ( /* check if it is NOT within a class */ )
   {
      wrong=true;
      break;
   }
}
if (wrong)
{
  // here you know that at least one thing was NOT within a class B
}
else
{
  // here you know that every item A was within a class B
}
```

In your case the "class" is "Strings with no space" and to check if there is space you just use [this condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340309/2893496).

Comment: Thx for helping