# Is there an "includes()" method in c++ like there is in javascript

Tags: javascript, c++

I've been trying to get a specific string from another string in c++, and I was wondering if there was an "includes()" method like there is in javascript, which returns true if the string parameter is inside the other specified string. If not, what would be the closest thing to it?

Comment: You probably want [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: What does your C++ book say, as far as available `std::string` methods go? Do any one of the many `std::string` methods look like something that you're looking for? Which C++ `std::string` methods you know, already?

Comment: Tip: When you phrase your question that way, you restrict your audience to people who know both JavaScript and C++. If you took the time to explain the functionality of "includes()", you would expand your audience. (I don't know by how much, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340281/check-if-a-string-contains-a-string-in-c).

The `std::string::find` function will return the position of the "substring" inside the string. If the substring is not found, it returns `std::string::npos`.

An `includes()` function may look like:

```
bool includes(const std::string &str, const std::string &subStr) {
    return (str.find(subStr) != std::string::npos);
}
```