# Counting vowels c++

Tags: c++

While user inputs 10 alphabets, program should tell how many of them are vowels. I have written this code:

```
while (count<10)
    {
        cin >> n;
        count++;
        if (n == 'A' || n == 'a' && n == 'E' || n == 'e' && n == 'I' || n == 'i' && n == 'O' || n == 'o' && n == 'U' || n == 'u')
            {
                total++;
            }
    }

cout <<  total << endl;
```

This generates output of 0 even if there are vowels entered by user. something wrong?

Comment: replace `&&` with `||`

Comment: Replace all `&&` by `||`. Also what is the type of `n`? Provide a [mre].

Comment: Your code checks to see if a character is *simultaneously all five vowels*!

Comment: Please, read this literally: No character can be an `A` or `a` and an `E` or `e` and ... Output of 0 is the obviously correct answer for any input. ;-)

Comment: @n314159 sorry I had this view in mind that if I put || (or) there, it will just check the first condition and will add A/a to the total without checking rest of them.

Comment: Reduce your comparisons by half, by using `std::toupper` or `std::tolower`.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews If using `std::tolower` or `std::toupper` one should make the `n` an `unsigned char`.

Comment: @n314159:  Please document the reference where you got this idea.  My understanding is that [`std::toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) takes a *signed* int as the parameter.  Passing a `char` will automatically get converted.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Sorry, I missread the reference you linked a bit. But compare this with [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit). It has the same signature and has a note that one should cast to `unsigned char`.

Comment: @n314159:  Two different functions.  Please quote the section of the C++ standard where the functions must have the same signature. (You may want to browse to the sections about `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`).

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Sorry, I was unclear. I don't claim anymore that `std::tolower` needs an `unsigned char`. I am just confused why `std::isdigit` needs that and `std::tolower` does not, when both are functions taking an `int` that has to be representable by `unsigned char` (this precondition is stated on cppreference).

Comment: @n314159: You should ask this as a separate question.  Please also see the function versions declared in `<locale>`, [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower), [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isdigit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start by cutting down the condition down a bit, to only look at `a` and `e`

```
if (n == 'A' || n == 'a' && n == 'E' || n == 'e')
```

and then only considering the lowercase letters for simplicity (but retains the problem)

```
if (n == 'a' && n == 'e')
```

if you read this out loud it says "if `n` is `'a'` AND `n` is '`e'`". The "AND"  (from the `&&` operator) means that *both* conditions must be true. You've created an impossible condition here, if `n` is `'a'`, then it is not `'e'`, so you get `if (true && false)` - which is false. If `n` is `'e'`, then it is not `'a'`, so you get `if (false && true)`.

Simply replace all of your `&&` (and) operators with `||` (or) operators to have the condition be true if at least one of your equality comparisons is true.

```
if (n == 'A' || n == 'a' || n == 'E' || n == 'e' 
    || n == 'I' || n == 'i' || n == 'O' || n == 'o' 
    || n == 'U' || n == 'u')
```

---

There are some ways to simplify the condition.

One is to add a `#include <cctype>` and use [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) to convert `n` to lowercase, then you only need to compare against lowercase characters.

```
n = std::tolower(n);
if (n == 'a' || n == 'e' || n == 'i' || n == 'o' || n == 'u')
```

Another, less repetitive approach is to create a `std::string` with all the vowels in it, and then [see if it contains `n`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340281/check-if-a-string-contains-a-string-in-c), `#include <string>` up top.

```
std::string vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
while (/*...*/) {
   // ...
   if (vowels.find(n) != std::string::npos) {
     ++total;
   }
}
```

As [n314159](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345656/n314159) pointed out, if you are using C++17 or later, you can use a `std::string_view` instead, which is cheaper. `#include <string_view>`

```
static constexpr std::string_view vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";   
while (/*...*/) {
   // ...
   if (vowels.find(n) != std::string_view::npos) {
     ++total;
   }
}
```

Comment: I overlooked that `&&` has higher precedence than `||`. However, even considering this, it doesn't become better... ;-)

Comment: On C++17 I would recommend substituting the `std::string` by an `constexpr std::string_view` since it may be cheaper and the compiler should be able to optimize it more.

Comment: @scypx Please, don't forget to mark an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Hm, it would be interesting if `std::tolower` and then `find` on a smaller string is faster than `find` the long string. I mean, `std::lower` (if it is unsafe) should implementable by one subtraction. Not that it is in any way relevant^^

Comment: @scypx A solution without using `std::tolower` but bit operations: `if ((n|=0x20) && (!(n^'a') || !(n^'e') || !(n^'i') || !(n^'o') || !(n^'u')))`

Comment: @urbanSoft doesn't seem any better than `==` comparison, what does this handle that I'm missing

Comment: @RyanHaining It's not about beeing better rather than diffrent. Key part is `(n|=0x20)` which always sets bit no. 6 in `n`. When dealing with ANSI letters `n` will become (or stay) lowercase so there's no need to use `std::tolower`. To my mind it's an awesome feature of th ANSI table ([additional reading](https://catonmat.net/ascii-case-conversion-trick)).

Comment: @urbanSoft I get that, I'm not following why you are doing `!(n^'a')` instead of `n == 'a'`

Comment: @RyanHaining For no reason other than personal favour. Since I started with a bit operation i simply stuck with them.

Comment: @urbanSoft I would encourage you to use `==` when you mean "equals" if others will be reading your code. You will make a lot of enemies using unnecessary bit operations like this. Obviously nothing really matters if all you do is solo projects.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a `switch` statement with fall-through, which is more readable but also potentially more efficient (may be implemented with jump table).

```
int count = 10;
while (count--) {
    switch(std::tolower(n)) {
        case 'a': case 'e': 
        case 'i': case 'o': 
        case 'u': total ++; break;
        default:;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add `[[ fallthrough ]]` or get annoyed by compiler warnings.

Comment: @n314159 This doesn't give warning with either g++ or clang++ (even with -Weverything flag). I'm guessing they see the empty `case` body and they assume it's explicit enough.

Comment: @n314159 Hmm, you're actually right it sometimes gives a warning. Only for the non-empty `'u'` case though, so fixed it : )