# String Comparision

Tags: c++, string, comparison

How are the word files stored in a text file.

I am trying to take a word as input from  and comparing that word with the words present in my local path.

how to compare the input word to the words in the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string str;
fstream file;
string word, t, q, filename;

void read()
{
    cout << "Enter the word to search in the dictionary:";
    cin >> str;
    cout << "Your Entered word is :" << str;
    cout << "\nsearching in the librabry(Dictionary).";
    return;
}

void search()
{
    //string str;
    filename = "da1.txt";

    file.open(filename.c_str());
    if (str == word)
    {
        cout << "Found" << word << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nEntered word does not exist in the library." << endl;
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    search();
}
```

I am pretty sure that my word is not being compared to the words in the text.

Comment: It’s never too soon to stop using global variables.

Comment: also, stop using - using namespace std

Comment: Is it good that you doesn't use read() functiion?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here:

```
void read()
{
  cout<<"Enter the word to search in the dictionary:";
  cin>>str;
  cout<<"Your Entered word is :"<<str;
  cout<<"\nsearching in the librabry(Dictionary).";
  return;
}
```

and is caused because:

1. `read()` method is never called,
2. you ask for a **word** to search but assign that input to **str** variable
3. in search method you do `if(str==word)`  so you compare 2 non initialized objects
4. you should do something like `std::string str{};`

Answer (score 0):

Your are not calling your method `read()`, so your var `word` is `null`.
Secondly, it seems you want to know if `str` contain `word`, instead of a simple equal. Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340281/check-if-a-string-contains-a-string-in-c).
As noted @Paul Sanders, you are not reading data from your file