# Checking if a string contains a substring C++

Tags: c++, string, substring

I'm trying to make a program that checks if a string contains a substring of another string, but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//Struct to store information
struct strings {
    char string1[20], string2[20];
} strings;

//Function to check if the strings are equal
void equalCheck(){
    int check = 0, i = 0;
    while (strings.string1[i] != '\0' || strings.string2[i] != '\0'){
        if (strings.string1[i] != strings.string2[i]){
            check = 1;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (check == 0){
        cout << "The strings are equal" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "The strings are not equal" << endl;

}

//Function to check for a substring
void substringCheck(){
    if (strings.string1.find(strings.string2) != string::npos) {
        cout << "found!" << '\n';
    }

}

int main() {


    //Ask the user for two strings
    cout << "Please type the first string: ";
    cin >> strings.string1;
    cout << "Please type the second string: ";
    cin >> strings.string2;

    //Prints out the two strings
    //cout << "The two strings are " << strings.string1 << " and " << strings.string2;

    equalCheck();
    substringCheck();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the problem I get:

[image: Problem]

Any ideas?

Comment: char datatype does not have function find

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `std::string`? That one does have `find` method. If for some reason you insist on dealing with C-style strings, you are looking for `strstr` function.

Comment: Since you want to write in c++ this might answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340281/check-if-a-string-contains-a-string-in-c

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This is the first time i code in c++ :P so I dont really know what I'm doing

Comment: @AngelosFr Yeah thats the post i tried to follow, but i couldnt get it to work and i dont know why :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier for `strings` to have two `std::string` instead of two `char[20]`?

Then you would be able to say this with no problem:

```
if (strings.string1.find(strings.string2) != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "found!\n";
}
```

`char` is not a class like `std::string`, it doesn't have any member functions. This means `char[20].find` doesn't exist. `std::string` is a class, however. And it does have a member function called `std::string::find()`, so doing this to a `std::string` is legal.

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks! I did not know you could use ```std::string``` instead of char. First time in C++ and I'm used to ```char``` from C